# How to call serviceBusService.listTopics(function(err, listtopicsresult, response){})?

Tags: node.js, azure, servicebus

I'm trying to list all the topics in service bus with name and size. I call this method as :-

```
    var AZURE = require('azure');
    var serviceBusService = AZURE.createServiceBusService();

function ListTopic()
{
    serviceBusService.listTopics(function(err, listtopicsresult, response){
        if(!err)
        {
            console.log("err  ok");
        }
        else
        {
            console.log("err error: "+err);
        }

        if(listtopicsresult)
        {
            I get something here in listtopicsresult can't get the actual list with topic name 

            //console.log("listtopicsresult 0 "+listtopicsresult.getItem(0));
            //console.log("listtopicsresult size "+listtopicsresult.size);
            //console.log("listtopicsresult size "+listtopicsresult.size);
            //console.log("listtopicsresult index 0 "+listtopicsresult.indexOf(0));
            //console.log("listtopicsresult index 0 "+listtopicsresult.indexOf(1));
        }
        else
        {
            console.log("listtopicsresult error: "+listtopicsresult);
        }

        if(!response)
        {
            console.log("response  ok");
        }
        else
        {
            console.log("response error: "+response);
        }
    });
}
```

How do I get all topic size and with name? First I wanted make this call work. Perhaps then I could try to find out each topic  size. Wish someone could help me in this matter. Thanks in advance!

Comment: quick tip - have you tried doing a util.inspect(listtopicsresult)?  You need to require('util'), but it will let you know exactly what's being returned.

Comment: Thanks for tips! I can see all information regarding my topics. Here is two topic info given by util:-

Comment: Here is one truncated output. I can only use 600 char. So how do I parse or retrieve particulate data out of this. It is not a valid json data:-    [ { DefaultMessageTimeToLive: 'P10675199DT2H48M5.4775807S',
    MaxSizeInMegabytes: '1024',
    Status: 'Active',
    SupportOrdering: 'true',
    CountDetails: 
     { 'd2p1:ActiveMessageCount': '0',
    SubscriptionCount: '1',
    AutoDeleteOnIdle: 'P10675199DT2H48M5.4775807S',
    EntityAvailabilityStatus: 'Available',
    _: 
 ersion=2013-07',
       title: 'i',
       published: '2014-02-18T08:29:37Z',
       link: '' },
    TopicName: 'i' },

Answer (score 0):

The latest version 7.0.0 of `@azure/service-bus`(based on AMQP - which is faster/better performant) has been published. It offers `ServiceBusAdministrationClient` that lets you manage the service-bus resources.

For the problem in this question, here are a couple of examples on using `ServiceBusAdministrationClient` - [listingEntities.ts](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/master/sdk/servicebus/service-bus/samples/typescript/src/advanced/listingEntities.ts) and [administrationClient.ts](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/master/sdk/servicebus/service-bus/samples/typescript/src/advanced/administrationClient.ts)

I know this is a late reply, but just in case someone is running into issues with the older service-bus SDK for node and landed here, refer to the links below.

- [@azure/service-bus - 7.0.0](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/service-bus)
- [Samples for 7.0.0](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/tree/master/sdk/servicebus/service-bus/samples)
- [Guide to migrate from @azure/service-bus v1 to v7](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/master/sdk/servicebus/service-bus/migrationguide.md)